# Need help establishing a development procedure with git

Tags: git

My colleagues and I are working on a project and are using Git as our source control. Lately though, we've stumbled upon some annoying problems because of a lack of proper procedure (changes committed that shouldn't have been, files modified straight in production interfering with git pull and so on). As such, we're trying to come up with a proper procedure that'll allow us to better our coordination.

At the moment, we have two servers which are mirror of each other. One for production and one for dev (let's call them prod and dev). Also, we have one single Git server onto which both server can fetch their modifications.

What we've come up so far is this:

1) Setup a dev branch on all local machines as well as the dev server.

2) All local development is pushed on the dev branch.

3) Once changes have been tested and validated on the dev server, we merge the dev branch on the master branch and push/pull everything so that the production server gets updated.

Mind you, this procedure isn't perfect. For example, none of us is even sure that Git will behave as we think it will with the dev branch. Then, if we have two changes on the dev branch and only one of them is ready for production, how do we merge only the one we want on the master branch? Also, if we have an emergency fix to make, how do we go about that?

Anyway, any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is going to be closed as opinion-based. But check out the various "flows". The most well-known are probably [Git Flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) and [GitHub Flow](http://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html). There is also [GitLab Flow](https://about.gitlab.com/2014/09/29/gitlab-flow/), and I'm sure there are a few dozen others floating around. Don't get too wrapped up in the names; there is generally nothing stopping you from using one flow model with another system.

Answer (score 1):

I found it hard to trust Git at first, but as I've gotten used to it, I can't imagine how I developed before it. More importantly to your question, my co-workers and I followed the guide below to get us started.

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Hogan

Comment: For a simplified view of the git-flow model you can also take a look at the [git-flow cheatsheet](http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/). It contains both the commands and explanations of the flow.